# How to identify that the protocol is using by AD DC is Kerberous?

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, ntlm

I have created a local environment as follows:-

```
DC:- Windows server 2008<br>
Client:- Windows 7<br>
Domain:- januapp.local
```

Now I read on somewhere that, the DC uses two types of Protocol for Authentication.

1.NTLM
2.Kerberous

Now when I type credentials of User listed in DC 'users' OU from client machine then I successfully logged in the domain but How I authenticated?

How this environment uses protocol? I want to see it in real, but I didn't find a way to do it so.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can install [windump/libpcap](https://www.winpcap.org/windump/) on a Windows client and see how it's communicating with DC via the network, by sniffing the traffic and analyzing the packet capture windump will get it with the [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) (or, simply analyzing the network traffic online with the latter).

I guess you will see that both protocols are used, but on different stages.

Answer (score 0):

windows logs security event 4768 for each Kerberos tgt request (event 4771 is logged for preauth failures).  To view the traffic itself you would need wireshark or message analyzer.